# Can I use "maritime" as a noun?

Tags: meaning, nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech

so far as I know, "maritime" is an adjective though

From time to time I see people who use it like a noun.

It was not a written article. The person was saying about the ocean generally like future of the ocean and the value of it. And after some time suddenly the person used the word as a noun in a general way

There was no context of Canadian oceans when he was saying that.

If there is no other option then he might just make a mistake, repeatedly.

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: The "Maritimes" are how people refer to Canada's maritime provinces, but I've never heard any singular usage for that. That said, if you had a choice between, say, a maritime province or a landlocked province, you could certainly say "I'll take the maritime" and it would be a case of using an adjective as a noun, which is fine in English. When the valet asks which car is yours, you can grammatically say, "Mine is the red."

Comment: That's not a very good "sample" -- it completely lacks context.

Comment: @HotLicks OK, it is not a written article. The person was saying about the ocean generally like future of the ocean and the value of it. And after some time suddenly the person used the word as a noun in a general way.

Comment: It's not uncommon for someone, when speaking, to use, say, "maritime law" once in their discussion, and then just say "maritime" subsequently as a sort of "nickname".  Without knowing the prior context we cannot guess at what was meant in this case.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah I know it, now I can see there is no other option except for the case you have just said to me.

Answer (score 2):

When you hear someone speaking of [*the maritimes*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maritimes), which is clearly a noun plural form, they are actually referring to the Canadian maritime provinces. At least, that’s what Merriam-Webster says in the linked definition:

> ## Maritime Provinces
>
> #### *geographical name*
>
> #### variants: or *the Maritimes*
>
> the Canadian provinces of New Brunswick, Nova Scotia, and Prince Edward Island —formerly considered by some to include also Newfoundland and Labrador — see Atlantic Provinces.

Comment: Ha, you beat my comment by 6 seconds. Great minds ... +1, btw.